# C++ like debugging in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

In the beginning I started learning to program with C++,for that I used Viusal C++, I had a debugging mode in Visual C++ where I could look what values variable have on Run-Time.As JS code is executed in browser I have to consider my self what values variables have. I want to know if there is some debugger available for JS where I can see values changing o0n Run-Time. Because of not knowing about any such debugger I have to spend more time while trying to figure out logical error.

Comment: Maybe Chrome devtools will help: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Alternatively, there's [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: So, you haven't even tried to ask google for that? "how to debug javascript" provides tons of info. Next time - ask http://google.com **before** stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Inspect variables in IE -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#_vars
- Watch variables in Firefox -
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger#Watch_expressions
- Watch variables in Chrome -
  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks?hl=en#favorite-expression

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for debugging just JavaScript by itself, check this question:
[JavaScript IDE/Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735211/javascript-ide-compiler)