# JavaScript IDE/Compiler

Tags: javascript, debugging, ide, javascript-debugger, script-debugging

Now, I hope some of you people will understand what I'm asking. I'm new to programming. I got introduced to JavaScript on Codecademy.com

I use labs.codecademy.com for my JavaScript writing, but it's limited. What IDE/Compiler can I use that's pretty simplistic in terms of being new to programming. Where I'm not surrounded by buttons that I don't know how to use yet.

Does this even exist? A simple IDE?

Comment: I added more tags, so maybe this question will be more visible, and someone will provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think these two editors/IDEs are simple and good for beginners:

- [nodepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (with [Plugins](http://bateru.com/news/2012/04/4-notepad-plugins-for-javascript-developers/))
- [sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (with [Plugins](http://code-tricks.com/best-sublime-text-plugins/))

More "complicated", but good javascript support:

- [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)

This is very subjective, but nevertheless have look at this editors and choose what suites best for you.

I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad?  JavaScript doesn't have a compiler really.  Though there are ways of shrinking the code that some people call "compiling" but it isn't "compiling" in the strictest sense of the word.

If you are looking for something JavaScript specific, give http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ a try.  The personal license is $50 and I'm sure that while it will do more than you need right now, it will grow with you. There is a 30 day trial.

Comment: notepad is not the same as notepad++. notepad++ supports a lot of languages and is quite nice for beginners.

Comment: Yes, I realize that..  My point is, if you want something "simplistic" notepad is as "simplistic" as it gets.

Comment: The thing is, is that I know that I can use notepad, and write JavaScript in with HTML. JavaScript is mainly used for HTML. But I'd like to be able to run JavaScript independently with a console.

Comment: @user3474711 This is possible with sublimetext. Have a look at this post: http://calebgrove.com/articles/js-console-sublime-text

Comment: If you want to run java in a console. Take a look at nodejs

Comment: @DaveBush What has Java to do with nodejs? Do you mean Javascript?

Comment: Yes. JavaScript. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this exact question for my daughter. Like you, she started learning JavaScript on Codecademy. She loves it, but she is frequently frustrated, when she doesn't understand why a program doesn't work.

So, I researched IDEs and debuggers, and I read that Visual Studio has a debugger that is easy to use. But after installing 4 different versions, I had to jump through lots of hoops to create a JavaScript project in Visual Studio Express 2013, and then I couldn't debug it.

After a while I gave up and installed Eclipse. I have used Eclipse before, and it's very powerful. I was originally looking for alternatives, because I felt using Eclipse for JavaScript is kind of like using an airplane, when all you need is a bicycle :)

There are many versions and packages of Eclipse. I think this one might be the simplest to install:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliossr2
(Helios is a version, and this specific package is for JavaScript developers)

I actually used the latest version (Kepler). Unfortunately it doesn't have a package for JavaScript, so I used the Java package:
http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2
and then added JSDT:
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/

Yes, Eclipse can be intimidating for a beginner, but the good thing about Eclipse is that it works on multiple platforms, you can find support for pretty much any language, and it's free :)

If you are serious about programming, I recommend you invest a little time in learning how to use Eclipse.

Let me know if this helps, or if you have more questions.